# How to add user in centos without manual password prompt

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I am trying to automate setting up a user on centos as part of my script. Here is what i am doing:-

```
/usr/sbin/useradd my-user
/usr/bin/passwd my-user
```

> You will be be prompted to enter password for the my-user user

Now is there a way to skip the second command so that there is no manual prompt, so that i can have something in the script to auto create my-user on centos without needing to manually enter the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change password programmatically, using:

```
echo -e "xyz\nxyz\n" | /usr/bin/passwd my-user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use chpasswd command with echo. Here is a simple example

```
/bin/echo my-user:password | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```